# Deploy Flask on Azure using Kudu - shows only default page

Tags: python, azure, flask, kudu

I built and deployed Flask app in Python to Azure. I tested the app locally and everything works. I am using Kudu for deployment on Windows and Python 3.6.

However, once the app is successfully deployed, all I can see is the default page:

> This website is running Python 3.6.6

From what i saw, the fault is on the Kudu `web.config` file, which looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="pythonpath" value="%SystemDrive%\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="hostingstart-python.application" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

For some reason, it points to the `hostingstart-python.application` (has `.html` and `.py` files) which indeed shows the default page.

My `/wwwroot` folder looks as follows:

```
env
templates
.gitignore
app.py
config.py
file_manager.py
hostingstart-python.html
hostingstart-python.py
README.md
requirements.txt
web.config
```

I tried various versions of the `web.config` file, such as the one below, but without any luck.
For `WSGI_HANDLER` I put name of the web app, but perhaps another name has to be there?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="UploadToolApp.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python364x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x64/scripts\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Which results in:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Comment: Try `<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.*whatever-your-app-is-called-inside-app.py*"/>` e.g. `<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.app"/>`. Also note Python support on Azure Windows App Service is deprecated.

Comment: In the end I used Linux and everyting works just fine. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to switch to Linux machine, then everything works as it supposed to.